# Can't add Lottie animation view to collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, lottie

I was trying to add LOTAnimationView to my collection view cell, but nothing appears on the screen when I run the program.Here is the [link](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios) to lottie. And Here is the code:

```
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell{

var animationView: LOTAnimationView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super .awakeFromNib()
    animationView = LOTAnimationView(name: "Animation")
    self.contentView.addSubview(animationView!)

}
```

Comment: Ok, what's a Lottie animation? If it's a third party animation framework you might want to add a link or some additional information.

Comment: Lottie is Airbnb's open source animation framework, @DuncanC

Answer (score 0):

1- is you JSON animation has been added to your target?
2- verify that your animation file is Animation.json

Comment: yea, its a JSON file and it's been added to the target. I can add the animation to a normal view just fine, but when I try to place it in UICollectionViewCell nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You just created an instance and added it to the subview which is cool.. 
Where are you calling the 'Play()' command, is it from the datasource/delegate class? 
Try calling the 'Play()' command in the custom cell itself i.e. in awakeFromNib() method. It should work.